# attack by some bot

Tags: python, django, security

I think I was attacked. what are the best measures to avoid such attacks during development ? Below is what showed up on my terminal

This was at the beginning of my terminal

```
[03/Aug/2013 16:37:36] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x00')
[03/Aug/2013 16:37:36] " " 400 -
[03/Aug/2013 16:37:39] "GET http://server4.cyberpods.net/azenv.php HTTP/1.1" 404
[03/Aug/2013 16:37:43] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x04\x01\x00P@\xfb\x0f\xcf0\x00')
```

This was at the end

```
[03/Aug/2013 16:37:45] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x05\x01\x00')
[03/Aug/2013 16:37:45] "♣☺ " 400 -
[03/Aug/2013 16:37:48] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x05\x01\x00')
[03/Aug/2013 16:37:48] "♣☺ " 400 -
```

Comment: Did you happen to post an address that people could access?  Normally unless it's essential for someone to do so - there are reserved domains of example.com for instance so that you can give examples of URL structure without giving a live site...

Comment: @JonClements I don't know maybe given my port

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Random weird requests happen all the time to webservers around the world. Misconfigured clients, botnets and other malware are responsible, and there's little you can do about it.

But in this case, the client had no idea what they were doing because they even failed to adhere to the HTTP protocol:

```
GET http://server4.cyberpods.net/azenv.php HTTP/1.1
```

The GET line cannot contain a full URL, but must contain only the (absolute) path, `/azenv.php` in this case. Your server correctly responded with "400 Bad Request" which basically means "I have no friggin' idea what you're asking".

They might be probing your server for vulnerabilities, but if your software (mainly, your webserver and Django) is up to date, there's little to worry about.

Just to be sure: did you mean to expose this site to the entire internet? If not, you might want to look into your router/firewall settings. Exposing all ports on a Windows machine to the entire internet is generally a Bad Idea™.

Comment: I just want to learn and do things safely without harming my pc or anyone else. I didn't get what you mean by exposing this site ? Are you referring to the one which I'm working on or the one mention above. Sorry if my question is too dumb, I'm still a noob. And I don't mean to expose anything. I will do as you say. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Thomas: I think the client had a perfectly good idea what they were doing: exploiting (or probing) vulnerabilities in some software that doesn't handle malformed HTTP GETs properly. They're trying to see how the server will respond, and might follow it up with more probes or random attempts to hit the server.

Comment: @user2539745: These sorts of requests are totally random, and happen because your computer was visible on the public Internet. If you wanted to make it publicly visible, then that's fine. If it's just for your own testing purposes, consider firewalling it so only your local network can access the server (this will protect you from external requests like these ones)